# How to ensure a user tag number (like discord) is not already taken for a given username

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to implement a user tagging system like the number tags that discord users have. I have a randomly generated tag number for each user, and in the event the user decides to change their name I have to make sure that the tag the user already has does not conflict with another user that has the same name and coincidentally same tag. I also was not sure if I should be building the tag checker within my manager or my models file.

I was thinking of doing a filter for each user with the same name and query for all the tags of the users with the name and pick a number that isn't taken, but I feel like there might be a more obvious solution to this than that.

Heres my models.py for the user

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from random import randint
from accounts.manager import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email adress'), unique=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user_tag = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['alias', 'password']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.alias}#{self.user_tag}"

    def generate_new_tag(self):
        self.user_tag = randint(1000, 9999)
```

Heres the manager.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from random import randint

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers for authentication instead of usernames.
    Aliases are a username that can be taken by another user but differentiated by a tag
    """
    def create_user(self, email, alias, password, **extra_fields):
        # Create and save a User with the given email and password, automatically generate a tag
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, alias=alias, user_tag=randint(1000, 9999), **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

TLDR; Simplest query to return user_tags that are taken for a given alias and where should I be placing the tag generator code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to use a [UUID field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) for your tags:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from random import randint


class CustomUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user_tag = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.alias}#{self.user_tag}"
```

It ensures that all generated UUIDs will be unique. See the [`uuid` standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#module-uuid).

**Edit:** UUIDs have fixed length. If you want short tags, I think the most efficient way to select a unique one would be to generate all available tags and remove already taken ones:

```
from random import choice
...

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    def generate_new_tag():
        tags = set(range(1000, 9999))
        taken_tags = set(CustomUser.objects.values_list('user_tag', flat=True))
        return choice(list(tags - taken_tags))

    user_tag = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, default=generate_new_tag)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email adress'), unique=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ...
```

This approach hits database only once and is fast, because a set possible tags is quite small.

Comment: Would it be possible to set a custom length to the UUID? I was thinking with using a 4 digit tag because if each possible username can have about 9000 users with the same alias that should be enough to say that you can have any alias you would like.

Comment: Since your concern seems to be when a user name is updated the new name+tag now conflicts with an existing name+tag. If so the easiest process would just b e put a unique constraint of those fields. This **could** have the benefit reducing the code as it's no longer necessary to check for an existing pair - Postgres will do it for you - but of course means handling the error (23000 integrity_constraint_violation) when the conflict occurs.

Comment: @KalinKochnev I have updated my answer to include solution for short tags.